# A synonym for the expression "most used"

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

Since most expressions starting with `most "insert adjective"` have a substitute, e.g. `most pretty` turns into `prettiest`, or `most strong` turns into `strongest`, is there a substitute as well for `most used`?

Comment: Actually, _most pretty_ and _most strong_ become _prettiest_ and _strongest_, respectively.

Comment: "commonest" comes close .  But "most common" and "most used" do mean slightly different things...depending on what you are referring to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Used" in this case is the past participle of "to use" acting as an adjective. Past participles do not get the -er or -est endings. "Most used" is the correct way to say this.

Also, not all adjective receive the -er or -est. You can say "most beautiful" but not "beautifulest."